# How can I show "sold out" instead of "out of stock" for some products with particular tags and categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

hello comrades
How can I show **sold out** instead of **out of stock** for some products with particular tags and categories.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', function() {
global $product;
if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
   echo '<span class="now_sold_list">out of stock</span>';
}
});

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', function() {
global $product;
if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
   echo '<span class="now_sold_single">out of stock</span>';
});
```

Comment: WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_out_of_stock_text_woocommerce', 1, 2);

function change_out_of_stock_text_woocommerce( $availability, $product_to_check ) {
    
   
    if ( ! $product_to_check->is_in_stock() || has_term( 'my-ex-cat-slug', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'my-ex-tag-slug', 'product_tag' )) {
        
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sold Out', 'woocommerce');
        
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Change `my-ex-cat-slug` with your Category's slug and `my-ex-tag-slug` with tag's slug